# Issues with twitter geocode parameter in twitter search api

Tags: twitter, geolocation

I am trying to get twitter feeds using twitter search api with geocode params. I am setting the get param as

```
$getfield = '?geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,1mi&lan=en&result_type=mixed'
```

However, I get the following tweets which are like from everywhere around the world. Can anyone provide some suggestions?

```
Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:04:53 +0000 2013
id => 4.15226528894E+17
text => Ye said hope d rose aight lol http://t.co/4vpDCFJQyV
source => Instagram
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 27260086
User name => Justin Bieber
User scree name => justinbieber
User location => All Around The World
Description => #MusicMondays is in effect. Unlock #FilmFridays - SO MUCH LOVE FOR THE FANS...you are always there for me and I will always be there for you. MUCH LOVE. thanks
Protected => 
Followers count => 47889293


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:03:03 +0000 2013
id => 4.15226068632E+17
text => Good first half that !
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 105119490
User name => Niall Horan
User scree name => NiallOfficial
User location => Mullingar,Westmeath,Ireland
Description => i like climbing trees ! NOW! KETCHUP
Protected => 
Followers count => 16222287


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:20:28 +0000 2013
id => 4.15230451583E+17
text => Cowboys QB Tony Romo has been ruled out the rest of the season due to his back injury, per league source.
source => UberSocial for BlackBerry
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 51263592
User name => Adam Schefter
User scree name => AdamSchefter
User location => New York
Description => Father, Husband, Son, University of Michigan graduate, and NFL Insider for ESPN. http://t.co/TaDqSuzq8x.
Protected => 
Followers count => 2610005


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:23:41 +0000 2013
id => 4.15231258747E+17
text => BREAKING: Tony Romo is out for rest of the season with a back injury. (via @AdamSchefter)
source => web
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 26257166
User name => SportsCenter
User scree name => SportsCenter
User location => Rockin' Bristol, CT since 1979
Description => All things sports, all the time. Nominate top plays using #SCtop10. *If you send us a tweet, you consent to letting ESPN use and showcase it in any media*
Protected => 
Followers count => 6449755


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:22:03 +0000 2013
id => 4.15230850247E+17
text => BREAKING: Dallas Cowboys QB Tony Romo has been ruled out for the remainder of the season due to his back injury. (via @AdamSchefter)
source => web
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 123417995
User name => NFL on ESPN
User scree name => ESPNNFL
User location => Bristol, CT
Description => ESPNâ€™s official NFL coverage. Sunday NFL Countdown, Monday Night Countdown, NFL LIVE, NFL Insiders and Audibles.
Protected => 
Followers count => 490234


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:15:59 +0000 2013
id => 4.15229321146E+17
text => uploaded some Christmas photos on facebook :) #JOLLYSOS https://t.co/uRc54hAOhZ http://t.co/PsplLRhBSZ
source => TweetDeck
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 264107729
User name => 5 Seconds of Summer
User scree name => 5SOS
User location => Sydney, Australia
Description => 4 aussies making music :) love the people who support us! @ashton5sos @calum5sos @michael5sos @luke5sos
Protected => 
Followers count => 1771953


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:09:02 +0000 2013
id => 4.15227574219E+17
text => do u ever get the urge to clean ur entire room and then 5 minutes after u start youâ€™re like nah son and u just lay on the floor
source => web
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 956730660
User name => can you not
User scree name => sassytbh
User location => professional booty clapper
Description => Fabulous, feisty, fearless, feminine and fierce.
Protected => 
Followers count => 299996


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 20:45:52 +0000 2013
id => 4.15221741653E+17
text => #JustDance2014 is giving you a chance to come to s show & hang out so make a Mahomie ecard now!!(: http://t.co/UROLlwsaX6
source => web
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 196795202
User name => Austin Mahone
User scree name => AustinMahone
User location => Miami, FL 
Description => Thank you guys for the love and support!! WATCH MY NEW VIDEO FOR #BangaBanga http://t.co/LbogjD8w6v
Protected => 
Followers count => 4835975


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:46:10 +0000 2013
id => 4.15236916755E+17
text => do u ever just sit there with your legs open and then remember you are a girl
source => Buffer
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 147305691
User name => FAT AMY
User scree name => RelatableQuote
User location => 
Description => The names Fat Amy. I call myself that so twig bitches like you don't do it behind my back. *Parody account* // Contact: contactrelatablequote@gmail.com
Protected => 
Followers count => 2145966


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:01:10 +0000 2013
id => 4.15225594399E+17
text => Our February cover star is the gorgeous and talented @ArianaGrande!: http://t.co/cNY9sWaWJl
source => HootSuite
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 24190981
User name => Teen Vogue
User scree name => TeenVogue
User location => 
Description => Fashion starts here.
Protected => 
Followers count => 1888844


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 20:46:13 +0000 2013
id => 4.15221829331E+17
text => How to let your turtle roam around without losing him. http://t.co/A8hHbKVgf9
source => Buffer
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 978908012
User name => Fascinating Pictures
User scree name => Fascinatingpics
User location => Founder of
Description => Fascinating pictures of places, people, animals and nature. We show you the world. We do not claim rights to our pictures. fascinatingpictures@gmail.com
Protected => 
Followers count => 927750


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:16:06 +0000 2013
id => 4.15229349252E+17
text => The Club can announce that Tim Sherwood has been appointed Head Coach with a contract to the end of the 2014/15 season
source => web
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 121402638
User name => Tottenham Hotspur
User scree name => SpursOfficial
User location => Tottenham, London, England
Description => Welcome to the Official Twitter page for Tottenham Hotspur Football Club, where you can get your official Club news, competitions and more!
Protected => 
Followers count => 725499


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:23:27 +0000 2013
id => 4.1523120045E+17
text => Home Made Hair Treatments http://t.co/LZpfvGiC8p
source => TweetDeck
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 552594595
User name => Girl Tweets
User scree name => FemaleB00K
User location => 
Description => Hey beautiful.. â¤
Protected => 
Followers count => 96554


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 20:43:23 +0000 2013
id => 4.15221117952E+17
text => ÙˆØ§Ù„Ù„Ù‡ Ø­Ø²Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø§Ù… Ù…Ø¨ÙƒÙŠ ÙˆØ±ØµØ§Øµ Ø¨Ø´Ø§Ø±Ù‚Ø§ØªÙ„ ÙˆØ§Ù†ÙŠÙ†Ù‡Ù… Ù…Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø«Ù„ÙˆØ¬ Ù…Ø­Ø²Ù† Ø¹Ø§Ø±Ø¹Ù„ÙŠÙ†Ø§ Ø¨Ø£Ù† Ù†Ø±Ù‰ ÙˆÙ„Ø§Ù†ØªØµØ¯Ù‚ Ù„Ù‡Ù… Ø¨Ø´ÙŠ ÙŠØ¯ÙØ¦Ù‡Ù… Ø¹Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø¨Ø±Ø¯ Ø§Ù„Ù‚Ø§ØªÙ„ http://t.co/leH4iW9Cor
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 367582515
User name => Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø§Ø¨
User scree name => al3raabq8q8
User location => 0096566623330
Description => Ù„Ù„Ø¯Ø¹Ù€Ø§ÙŠØ© ÙˆØ§Ù„Ø¥Ø¹Ù€Ù€Ù„Ø§Ù† Ù…Ø¹ Ø§Ù„Ù€Ù€ØÙ€Ø±Ø§Ø¨Ù€Ù€Ù€ Ø±Ø§Ø³Ù„Ù†Ø§ Ø¹Ø¨Ø± Ø§Ù„ÙˆØ§ØªØ³ Ø£Ø¨
Protected => 
Followers count => 1382919


Language => popular
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:41:56 +0000 2013
id => 4.1523585094E+17
text => This game needs a world class striker. http://t.co/IdrdPMnu6S
source => TweetDeck
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 365953260
User name => Football Funnys
User scree name => FootballFunnys
User location => England
Description => The one & the original, accept no imposters. Bringing you all the best jokes, pictures and facts.
Protected => 
Followers count => 861372


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:57:12 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239695456E+17
text => RT @Cuaimalosa: Esta tienda >>>>>>>>>>>> http://t.co/KHjPqyT6OH
source => web
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 284822197
User name => OkonerCandanga
User scree name => BrianOkonerGep
User location => 
Description => Futuro escritor... TE ADORO ZULEIKA *-* PIN; 28FCFB17 â™¥_â™¥ 21.12.12 ZYGR
Protected => 
Followers count => 609


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:57:12 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239694151E+17
text => Carrying home a Christmas tree. I'm still not used to this Christmas + warm sun + sweat + palm treesâ€¦ http://t.co/N96G5uvIBx
source => Instagram
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 14621941
User name => Harlan Crystal
User scree name => harlancrystal
User location => San Francisco, CA
Description => Founder & CTO of Pocket Gems
Protected => 
Followers count => 520


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:57:02 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239653391E+17
text => RT @Cuaimalosa: Esta tienda >>>>>>>>>>>> http://t.co/KHjPqyT6OH
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 121922067
User name => Albany MalavÃ©
User scree name => DaysofAba
User location => Cuidad Bolivar/ MaturÃ­n js
Description => Diosâ¤ï¸.18. Futura cirujano cardiovascular y Futura Gineco- Obstetra. Pero por ahora soy solo una estudiante de medicina Udista. Baby @1claseSpecial 22/10/2013â¤ï¸
Protected => 
Followers count => 636


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:56:59 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239640321E+17
text => RT @keytokidrauhl_: I wanna go out today ...
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 1279057460
User name => Nina Caton
User scree name => itsmrssykes_
User location => 
Description => @Nathanthewanted @JoshGoldenmusic
Protected => 
Followers count => 125


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:56:43 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239574257E+17
text => Received my new Rebel water resistant speaker via @Indiegogo! Love it. Wish I had ordered a 3-pack. http://t.co/pMQpJ2FckF
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 69399196
User name => Natasha Pecor
User scree name => NPecor
User location => San Francisco, CA
Description => Leading Platform BD @Yelp, Formerly Freestyle Capital, Duke (Fuqua) MBA, Cal Poly Engineer, tech enthusiast, & lover of vegetarian cuisine.
Protected => 
Followers count => 2062


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:56:40 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239558952E+17
text => RT @Cuaimalosa: Esta tienda >>>>>>>>>>>> http://t.co/KHjPqyT6OH
source => web
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 150881224
User name => â¥ â€
User scree name => VeroRdrgz
User location => Insta: verordrgz
Description => 16. (06 i love you Ã±ovia aquÃ­ gdjrmmâ¤).
Protected => 
Followers count => 1489


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:56:30 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239515826E+17
text => Farewell candlestick #goldblooded #thestick #keepfuckingupseattle
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 88371389
User name => Jonathan Le
User scree name => jonathanthongle
User location => 
Description => So it goes*
Protected => 
Followers count => 179


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:56:29 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239512139E+17
text => Esta tienda >>>>>>>>>>>> http://t.co/KHjPqyT6OH
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 177616310
User name => ana â˜¾
User scree name => Cuaimalosa
User location => Amo a @PoeTrollero
Description => El amor de mi vida, la mejor amiga del mundo @GabaaGonzalez. Mejores amigas @Moscarelliale @coralm__ â™¥
Protected => 
Followers count => 7354


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:55:58 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239383785E+17
text => But she's driving me insane!
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 287942657
User name => Michael Rose
User scree name => xenopeltis
User location => San Francisco, CA
Description => Singing and dancing in a rock n roll band
Protected => 
Followers count => 103


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:55:54 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239368396E+17
text => Always cheers me up no matter what http://t.co/gQ9qnlbUBj
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 287942657
User name => Michael Rose
User scree name => xenopeltis
User location => San Francisco, CA
Description => Singing and dancing in a rock n roll band
Protected => 
Followers count => 103


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:55:47 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239336008E+17
text => People have such bad taste in everything.
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 102180426
User name => Rachel
User scree name => rachietalksalot
User location => 
Description => what's the difference between sass and 'tude?
Protected => 
Followers count => 242


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:55:39 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239306052E+17
text => @lea_rosen @timhwang KB3TOS
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 4.15231959301E+17
in reply to screen name => lea_rosen
User id => 393224517
User name => Stuart Anderson
User scree name => emblem__
User location => San Francisco
Description => Security. Systems. Robotics. Bakatter.
Protected => 
Followers count => 932


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:55:34 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239284628E+17
text => I'm at @RadioShack (San Francisco, CA) http://t.co/J6hywgigZk
source => foursquare
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 1305220387
User name => Food/Tech Tales Guru
User scree name => foodtechtales
User location => San Francisco 94104
Description => Electronics, Food and Wine may have been my career fields for years on and off but one thing always going steady has been I telling a lot of tales about.....
Protected => 
Followers count => 109


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:55:24 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239241867E+17
text => {finally enjoying the beautifully decorated tree at the palace!} ðŸŽ„ @ Palace Hotel http://t.co/E88KEAjkgm
source => Instagram
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 285681235
User name => Kimberly Oulton
User scree name => misskimberlyo
User location => San Francisco
Description => Corporate + public affairs at @EdelmanPR. Active in @JuniorLeagueSF + @BayAreaCouncil. Former city + mayoral protocol representative. Views are my own.
Protected => 
Followers count => 441


Language => recent
Created at => Mon Dec 23 21:55:13 +0000 2013
id => 4.15239194576E+17
text => No homeless man I would not like to be your girl thnkz
source => Twitter for iPhone
in reply to => 
in reply to screen name => 
User id => 248058101
User name => Rachel
User scree name => sparklebabyxoxo
User location => 
Description => 
Protected => 
Followers count => 45
```

Comment: I am experiencing this problem now. Did you solve it?